# Audio processing steganography on iOS

Tags: audio, steganography

For one of our projects, we got a new requirement on our hands but I don't have any idea about how to do it.

We need to process audio captured from the environment and do something in the app (show a message, picture, etc) when a specific pattern is recognized.

The first thing that came to my mind when I heard this requirement was Shazam. I did a little research and found Echo Print library (http://echoprint.me). I think that works on the whole of the songs, what I need to do is constantly listen to environment and act when the patterns are recognized. I don't know anything about audio processing (at least for now) but this sounds more like steganography. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I think I need to correct some points in my question. Yes, the application will listen to the environment but it will recognize the patterns in a pre-configured audio. A specific song on a radio, a dog bark, etc. So the patterns will be artificially defined in the audio.

Thanks.

Comment: Steganography deals with embedding and extracting secret information from a medium. If you want to recognise a pattern based on the features of an audio track, steganography isn't the way to go unless the pattern has been previously artificially embedded.

Comment: My mistake, I tried to make my question more clear. We are trying to capture predefined patterns while listening to the environment. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to detect a barking dog sound in an environment full of other sounds, this is a job for machine learning or statistical inferences.

Comment: I am not trying to detect random sounds, I am trying to extract signatures from audio which are already defined in the application somewhere. I am just trying to find a way. If I am going to recognize the dog's bark, then that barking sound must have already defined exactly before.